# How to display plain-text response from a Server using HTTP GET in Angular2

Tags: angular, http-headers

I am working on **Angular-4** (most recent) with `@angular/cli` on Windows 10 with `npm v5.0.0` and `node v8.0.0`.

I have a server set up with actually gives response in **Plain-Text**.

I have a very simple interface where all I do is press a button and ask for **GET** request from my server. My goal is to show the plain text between `<p></p>`

#### Working of the server

```
http://servername.com/detectMeaning?keyword=mail
```

with **GET** gives me some text in plain-text.

### My Code

my component is called `simplesearch`

```
-- simplesearch/
               --simplesearch.component.ts
               --simplesearch.service.ts
-- app.component.ts
-- app.component.html
-- app.component.css
-- app.module.ts
```

**simplesearch.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SimplesearchService } from './simplesearch.service';
@Component({
   selector: 'app-simplesearch',
    template: `
    <button (click)="onTestGet()">GET Test</button>
    <p>{{getOutput}}</p>
    `,
    styles: [],
    providers: [SimplesearchService]
})
export class SimplesearchComponent {
  getOutput: string;

  constructor(private httpService: SimplesearchService) {}

  onTestGet() {
     this.httpService.getData()
      .subscribe(
        data => this.getOutput = data, // since data is plain-text
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  }
}
```

**simplesearch.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class SimplesearchService {
    private headers = new Headers();
    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.headers.append('Allow-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
     }

    getData(){
        return this.http
        .get('http://myserver.com:8090/detectMeaning?keyword=mail')
        .map(res => res.text());
    }
}
```

#### Error in Console for Mozilla Firefox

After the `XHR GET` request after the Button Push I get the error

`Object { _body: error, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Object, type: 3, url: null }`

I assume this is the JSON response I receive hence the `.JSON.stringify(data)` in my code.

I also end up getting the `CORS Header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` in the end. But I have added the header in the code already!

I have tried doing a `curl` on the URL for the same and there I get the result easily.

What are the necessary steps or improvements I should look into?

Comment: You should set up your server to accept CORS requests. This cannot be done with client headers

Comment: It looks like your request isn't successful at all, not that you can't get the plain text extracted from it. Can you check the dev tools from the browser and see if you get a proper response from the HTTP request there?

Comment: @AlexFlorin I did look into the dev tools of the browser and the Network analyses part shows the GET request gets the green sign but has an error with `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of JSON data`

Comment: That means that response content negotiation has failed. Have you set the `Content-type` header on server to have `text/plain` instead of `application/json`?

Comment: I suggest reading [this](http://restlet.com/company/blog/2015/12/10/understanding-http-content-negotiation/) article about HTTP content negotiation. It exemplifies using mostly `application/json` type, but the same principles can be used for any other format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API was available for usage after the Server was set up with [**CORS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) so that a cross-origin request could be made from the Frontend.

Also the final edit made where `this.getOutput = data` is used in my case since the available format is in plain-text and binding it into `JSON.stringify()` would actually lead to an error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of JSON data

which will be visible in the Debugger Tools under Network Analyses.